# how to send data from Blade view to controller in laravel to preform a post request

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to favorite and unfavorite posts and insert it in favorites table if clicked and     if clicked again it deletes it from favorites table  i put my routes in web.php file
the functions in the controller which should be called in the route  are not called i insert there `dd()` method to test it so i am guessing the problem is in the form action and not sending the data

```
<body>

...

@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="column">
        @if ($post->showstar == true)
            <form action="/favorites/delete" method="post">
                <span class="foo fa fa-star checked"></span>
            </form>
        @endif

        <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
        <img src={{$post->url}} >
    </div>
@endforeach
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on("click", ".foo", function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
                $(this).removeClass("checked");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("checked");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
class FavoritesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Favorites', ['favs' => Favorite::where('user_id', '1')->get()]);
    }

    public function view(Request $request)
    {
        dd("hello");
        $fav = new Favorite();
        $fav->user_id = $request->get('userid');
        $fav->post_id = $request->get('postid');
        $fav->save();
    }

    public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        dd("bye");
        $fav = new Favorite();
        $dfav = $fav->where('id', $request->id);
        $dfav->delete();

        return view('favorites');
    }

    public function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        $fav = new Favorite();
        $favs = $fav->where('user_id', $request->user_id);

        return view('favorites', compact('favs'));
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/favorites', 'FavoritesController@view');
Route::post('/favorites/delete', 'FavoritesController@delete');
Route::post('/favorites/fetch', 'FavoritesController@fetch');
```

Comment: You don't appear to submitting anything. Clicking on the span won't natively submit the form and even if it did, you don't have any data inside the form or an action that would suggest which post should be favourited/unfavourited. Please can you show your routes from your `web.php` file and also the code you have in your controller.

Comment: Done , my question is how to send the data to the controller

Comment: You need to put `@csrf` after `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try the plain and simple html form submit.

```
<form action="/favorites/delete" method="post">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
  <button>
    <span class="foo fa fa-star checked"></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

This way you can send the hidden input, post id in your case, to the controller and it will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a similar function ajax, to send data to a controller:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url:'youUrl',
    data:{'youData':"YourValueData"},
    type:'post',
    success:  function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(x,xs,xt){
        alert(x);

    }
});
```